# const char* vs const char[]

Tags: c++, c, string-literals, storage-duration

As far as I know , a string literal like "Hello"

is considered a `char*` in C and a `const char*` in C++ and for both languages the string literals are stored in *read-only* memory.(please correct me if I am wrong)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char* c1;
    const char* c2;

    {
        const char* source1 = "Hello";
        c1 = source1;

        const char source2[] = "Hi"; //isn't "Hi" in the same memory region as "Hello" ?
        c2 = source2;
    }

    printf("c1 = %s\n", c1); // prints Hello
    printf("c2 = %s\n", c2); // prints garbage

    return 0;
}
```

Why *source1* and *source2* behave differently ?*(compiled with gcc -std=c11 -W -O3)*

Comment: Assigning pointers in this way is **incorrect!** Use `strcpy`

Comment: @ForceBru I didn't get even any warning while compiling

Comment: The `source2` version temporarily creates a local array on the stack, which has gone out of scope by the time you print `c2`. If you want to mimic a string literal in a constant ("text") segment then use static instead of automatic storage.

Comment: I just tested it on gcc version 4.8.2 and it prints the following c1 = Hello
c2 = Hi
used the -std=c11 flag as well

Comment: In C++ string literals are type `const char []` of whatever length. They decay into `const char *` pointers.

Comment: Accessing the memory area of `source1` and `source2`  after they have gone out of scope invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Khan I'm terrible sorry , I added -O3 and then got the garbage, if could help me with this one , that would be great because now the answers are not exact

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In this code snippet

```
{
 const char* source1 = "Hello";
 c1 = source1;

 const char source2[] = "Hi"; //isn't "Hi" in the same memory region as "Hello" ?
 c2 = source2;
}
```

`source2` is a local character array of the code block that will be destroyed after exiting the block that is after the closing brace.

As for the character literal then it has static storage duration. So a pointer to the string literal will be valid after exiting the code block. The string literal will be alive opposite to the character array.

Take into account that in C the type of string literal `"Hello"` is `char [6]`. That is the type of any string literal is a non-const character array. Nevertheless you may not change string literals. Opposite to C in C++ character literals have types of const character arrays.

Comment: compiling without the -O3 option I get printed :
c1 = Hello
c2 = Hi

so know I'm confused

Comment: @Oleg The program behaviour is undefined when you try to access an object that is not already alive. Simply in the last case the memory early allocated for the array was not yet overwritten.

Answer (score 9):

```
const char* source1 = "Hello";
```

`source1` is just pointer on memory-location, where `Hello` is defined.

```
const char source2[] = "Hi";
```

`source2` is local variable of type array of chars and has another address, that string-literal `Hi`. After first `}` source2 will be destroyed and `c2` will be pointed somewhere, but not on location of `source2`, so it's just undefined behaviour to dereference `c2` after `source2` is destroyed.

Comment: so in this case "Hi" will be created in the same memory location as "Hello" but the content of "Hi" will be copied to a temp array source2 ?
after that I will lose my contents of the source2 array BUT "Hi" will still reside in my read only memory region ?

Comment: @Oleg yes, all string-literals are in read only memory region, but it's implementation-defined, that they are stored distinct, or not.

Comment: @Oleg undefined behaviour  is undefined.

Comment: you can see actual pointer value by usage of %p printf format modifier:In this case first string is really points to the text section  0x400754 but second string points to the stack  0x7fffaf9130c8, along with other local variables.

Answer (score 2):

> isn't "Hi" in the same memory region as "Hello"?

You are (subtly) mistaken. `"Hello"` *on it's own* is an *expression* that's not of type (`const`) `char *`, but of type (`const`) `char[6]`. `char source2[] = "Hi";` is a *statement* that defines, declares and initialises a `char [3]` object. There is no `const char *` in sight. In a function scope that object has automatic storage duration.

In your usage, `source2` ceases to exist at the following `}`, and makes `c2` an invalid pointer. The use of `c2` later is undefined.

Comment: @adabsurdum seems like I was missing a *not* in that sentence